# What is the future for the Craft rich text editor?

Tags: redactor, editor, wysiwyg

I can (almost) appreciate the recent impositions of Redactor 2, but when it comes to handing off the site to a client, Redactor 2 is virtually unusable for anything more than paragraph text.

Are there any other rich text editors being considered as core replacements in the future? If so, +1 for an implementation of [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) into Craft. I see there is already a [Yii2](https://github.com/froala/yii2-froala-editor) implementation available.

Comment: I really wish this question got more attention. I can't build client sites with Craft because redactor is too buggy and unpredictable.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, if a Craft CKEditor plugin doesn't come to life, then we might consider developing a 1st party (Pixel & Tonic) CKEditor plugin, although it would likely not replace the native Redactor Rich Tech Field implementation.

And of course, 3rd party plugins can implement whatever WYSIWYG they want to use.

Comment: Is there a reason people seem to hate Redactor? I see small complaints here and there, but no real big reason. I haven't used it enough to know what's up.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - If you ask me all WYSIWYG editors are evil.

Comment: @Erik: Redactor is a fine editor. (Emphasis on "fine"... not great, not terrible.) But they made some significant changes when Redactor 2 was released, many of which were viewed as a step _backwards_. The toolbar went from icons to text-only, several bugs were introduced, `<span>` tags were now getting removed, and pasted content was stripped down much more than before. Again, it's a "fine" editor, it just feels like development is moving _away from_ what people truly want.

Comment: @LindseyD as of the latest Craft release which includes Redactor 1.2.5 (https://imperavi.com/redactor/log/), `<span>` tags are back.

Comment: Woohoo! And a few other bugs are fixed, from what I understand. Thanks Brad!

Comment: @LindseyD interesting. Well, as long as it works, I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 3):

Asking us to predict the future is hard (and probably a little off-topic). But I'll go ahead and contribute what little knowledge I have...

Per conversations in Craft Slack, a few reputable plugin developers have casually mentioned that they may or may not be working on plugins for the following WYSIWYG editors...

- Froala
- CKeditor
- Tiny MCE

Because Slack conversations are so ephemeral, it's hard to say how much weight these comments truly carry. Multiple people mentioned working on a CKeditor, though it's possible they all stopped because "someone else is working on it". Froala was mentioned, although the cost was certainly an issue. And Tiny MCE was mentioned, although possibly as a joke.

I'd recommend tuning into [Craft Slack](https://craftcms.com/community#slack), where you may be able to get a more up-to-date answer to this question.

(Personally, I'd love to see a [P&T version](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15870/45) of the CKeditor. But that's like, [my opinion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c).)

Comment: The "problem" with CKEditor is that it is _butt ugly_ (though I guess the [Minimalist theme](http://ckeditor.com/addon/minimalist) could work with Craft) :D